# Retornar quantidade de itens agrupados SQL

Tags: sql

Possuo o seguinte SQL

```
SELECT `setor`.`set_setor` as age_status_texto, `prospect_agendamento`.`age_status`
FROM (`prospect_agendamento`)
JOIN `setor` ON `setor`.`set_cod`=`prospect_agendamento`.`age_status`
INNER JOIN `prospect` ON `prospect`.`pro_id`=`prospect_agendamento`.`age_id_prospect`
JOIN `unidade` ON `unidade`.`uni_id`=`prospect`.`uni_id`
JOIN `curso` ON `curso`.`cur_id`=`prospect`.`cur_id`
JOIN `usuario` ON `usuario`.`usu_id`=`prospect_agendamento`.`age_cod_consultora_agendado`
WHERE `age_data_agendado_para` BETWEEN concat('2017-04-01', ' 00:00:00') AND concat('2017-11-21', ' 23:59:59')
GROUP BY `prospect_agendamento`.`age_status`
ORDER BY `prospect_agendamento`.`age_data_agendado_para` DESC
```

Este é o resultado do SQL:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [age_status_texto] => 2 - Compareceu / matriculado
            [age_status] => 46
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [age_status_texto] => 3 - Compareceu / proposta
            [age_status] => 48
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [age_status_texto] => 5 - NÃ£o compareceu
            [age_status] => 53
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [age_status_texto] => 1 - No aguardo
            [age_status] => 50
        )

)
```

Minha ideia é agrupar por age_status, e eu preciso saber quantos registros de cada status eu tenho na tabela. Como eu faço? Uma vez que já agrupei o resultado.

Comment: Faz um [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) com suas estruturas e alguns dados, acho que fica mais fácil de entender!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para contar os registros é necessário usar a função de agregação `count()`.

Veja essa *query*:

```
SELECT `setor`.`set_setor` as age_status_texto,
`prospect_agendamento`.`age_status`,
count(`prospect_agendamento`.`age_status`) as quantidade_registros
FROM (`prospect_agendamento`)
JOIN `setor` ON `setor`.`set_cod`=`prospect_agendamento`.`age_status`
INNER JOIN `prospect` ON `prospect`.`pro_id`=`prospect_agendamento`.`age_id_prospect`
JOIN `unidade` ON `unidade`.`uni_id`=`prospect`.`uni_id`
JOIN `curso` ON `curso`.`cur_id`=`prospect`.`cur_id`
JOIN `usuario` ON `usuario`.`usu_id`=`prospect_agendamento`.`age_cod_consultora_agendado`
WHERE `age_data_agendado_para` BETWEEN concat('2017-04-01', ' 00:00:00') AND concat('2017-11-21', ' 23:59:59')
GROUP BY `prospect_agendamento`.`age_status`, `setor`.`set_setor`
ORDER BY `prospect_agendamento`.`age_data_agendado_para` DESC
```

Comment: Perfeito Laércio, a ideia é simplesmente essa mesma.

Comment: Funcionou contigo?

Comment: Editei o pois estava faltando a coluna `setor.set_setor` no *group by*, as colunas que não fazem parte do cálculo devem estar também no *group by*.

Comment: Funcionou sim, era o resultado esperado

Comment: Muito obrigado @LaercioLopes